# Django-cms : adding a video with a placeholder

Tags: html, django, django-cms

I'm trying to learn to use **django-cms**.

I'm trying to add a video (from *youtube*) on the default page.
I've tried to do it with an **iframe** (The code you can copy directly from youtube, cf. picture bellow) by copying it directly in a template, and then with the administration interface (adding a video with a youtube link in a placeholder).

[image]

I succeed with the **iframe**, but not with the **placeholder** : I just get a black rectangle.

[image]

Here is the code rendered by the development server :

```
<div>
  <div class="cms_placeholder cms_placeholder-6"></div>
  <div class="cms_plugin cms_plugin-18">
    <div class="plugin_video">
      <object id="video-plugin-18" width="420" height="315" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" >
        <param name="movie" value="/static/cms/swf/player.swf"/>
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="quality" value="autohigh" />
        <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="movie=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ynsBhCXm5Jk&amp;autoplay=false&amp;loop=false&amp;autohide=false&amp;fullscreen=true&amp;color_text=0xFFFFFF&amp;color_seekbar=0x13ABEC&amp;color_loadingbar=0x828282&amp;color_seekbarbg=0x333333&amp;color_button_out=0x333333&amp;color_button_over=0x000000&amp;color_button_highlight=0xFFFFFF" />
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <object width="420" height="315" data="/static/cms/swf/player.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
          <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
          <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
          <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="quality" value="autohigh" />
          <param name="wmode" value="opaque" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
          <param name="flashvars" value="movie=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ynsBhCXm5Jk&amp;autoplay=false&amp;loop=false&amp;autohide=false&amp;fullscreen=true&amp;color_text=0xFFFFFF&amp;color_seekbar=0x13ABEC&amp;color_loadingbar=0x828282&amp;color_seekbarbg=0x333333&amp;color_button_out=0x333333&amp;color_button_over=0x000000&amp;color_button_highlight=0xFFFFFF" />
          <!--<![endif]--><!-- alternate content -->
          Missing flash plugin. Please download the latest Adobe Flash Player: <br />
          <a href="https://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
            <img alt="Get Adobe Flash Player" src="/static/cms/img/icons/plugins/get_flash_player.gif" />
          </a>
          <!-- /alternate content --><!--[if !IE]>-->
        </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->
      </object>
    </div>
  </div>
  <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ynsBhCXm5Jk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
  </div>
```

I don't know why I have this problem, here is the content of my **pip freeze** :

```
dj-database-url==0.3.0
Django==1.7.8
django-classy-tags==0.6.1
django-cms==3.1.0
django-reversion==1.8.5
django-sekizai==0.8.1
Django-Select2==4.3.1
django-treebeard==3.0
djangocms-admin-style==0.2.7
djangocms-column==1.5
djangocms-file==0.1
djangocms-flash==0.2.0
djangocms-googlemap==0.2
djangocms-inherit==0.1
djangocms-installer==0.7.7
djangocms-link==1.6.1
djangocms-picture==0.1
djangocms-style==1.5
djangocms-teaser==0.1
djangocms-text-ckeditor==2.5.2
djangocms-video==0.1
html5lib==0.99999
Pillow==2.8.0
pytz==2015.4
six==1.9.0
tzlocal==1.1.3
wheel==0.24.0
```

I used a default page of a raw project.
I just added some lines in the **feature.html** template :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load cms_tags staticfiles sekizai_tags menu_tags %}

{% block title %}{% page_attribute 'page_title' %}{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<div class="jumbotron">
  {% placeholder "feature" %}
</div>
<!-- from here -->
<div>
  {% placeholder "test" %}
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ynsBhCXm5Jk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<!-- to here -->
<div>
  {% placeholder "content" %}
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

And added the first video via the admin interface.

**How should I add a video with placeholders?**

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is here, but to clear things up, placeholders hold CMS plugins. So out of the box, if you have a placeholder configured to hold the djangocms-video plugin, you should just have to add the movie URL. You shouldn't need to modify the templates.

Comment: @marksweb I didn't modify the template to use the plugin video, I modified the template to add bellow the code provided by youtube to check if this kind of video inclusion worked.

Comment: so is that code you posted which is rendered by the server the code generated by the plugin once you've saved it?

Comment: @marksweb Yes, except the **<iframe>...</iframe>** tags.

Comment: @vmonteco have you solved this? I tried to reproduce your problem, but I can add videos just fine using ``django==1.7.8``, ``django-cms==3.1.0`` and the video plugin (what you call the placeholder option).

Comment: I have the same issue with the "djangocms-video" plugin. It seems that it does not come with all necessary static files. I get javascript errors on the console that `static/cms/js/libS/swfobject.min.js` and `static/cms/swf/player.swf` cannot be found. Have you checked your javascript console?